# gcc: weak symbols compiled from template static member in static libraries seems lost during link

Tags: c++, c++17

We have some codes to dispatch a 'Gateway' object according to template class definition. A simplified version is as follows

First there is the factory definition: Factory.h

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <string>

class BaseGateway
{
public:
   virtual void hello() = 0;
protected:
   virtual ~BaseGateway() = default;
};

template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
   template <typename DERIVED_T>
   inline static DERIVED_T& CreateInstance() {
      if (ms_pInstance == nullptr) {ms_pInstance = new DERIVED_T();}
      return static_cast<DERIVED_T&>(*ms_pInstance);
   }
protected:
   static inline T* ms_pInstance;

   Singleton() {}
   virtual ~Singleton() = default;
};

class Gateway : public Singleton<Gateway>, public BaseGateway
{
protected:
   friend class Singleton<Gateway>; // for access to private ctor
   Gateway() = default;
   virtual ~Gateway() = default;
public:
   template<typename GatewayTraits>
   inline static const char *GetName() {
      return GatewayTraits::GetName();
   }
};

class Factory
{
public:
   using Dispatcher = std::map<std::string, BaseGateway*(*)()>;

   static Dispatcher & GetDispatcher() {
      static Dispatcher dispatcher;
      return dispatcher;
   }
};

template <typename GatewayTraits>
struct Dispatcher
{
   static inline struct EntryInserter
   {
      EntryInserter() {
         Factory::GetDispatcher().insert(
            {
               Gateway::GetName<GatewayTraits>(),
               []() -> BaseGateway*
               { return &Gateway::CreateInstance<typename GatewayTraits::GatewayType>(); }
            });
      }
   } m_EntryInserter;
   virtual ~Dispatcher() {
      (void)&m_EntryInserter;
   }
};
```

Then there are the Gateway templates: Gateway.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Factory.h"

template<typename SpecificTraits>
class GenericGateway : public Gateway, public Dispatcher<SpecificTraits>
{
protected:
   GenericGateway() = default;
   ~GenericGateway() override = default;
public:
   void hello() override { SpecificTraits::ProcessAndDisplay(m_value); }
private:
   typename SpecificTraits::ValueType m_value;
};

template<typename GatewayT>
struct IntTraits
{
   using GatewayType = GatewayT;
   using ValueType = int;
   static const char *GetName() { return "int_gateway"; }
   static void ProcessAndDisplay(ValueType &v) {
      v = 0;
      std::cout << v << std::endl;
   }
};

class IntGateway : public GenericGateway<IntTraits<IntGateway>>
{
protected:
   friend class Singleton<Gateway>;
   IntGateway();
   ~IntGateway() override = default;
};
```

Finally there are implementation and main function:

Impl.cpp

```
#include "Gateway.h"
IntGateway::IntGateway() = default;
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>
#include "Factory.h"
int main() {
   auto iter = Factory::GetDispatcher().find("int_gateway");
   assert(iter != Factory::GetDispatcher().end());
   auto * gateway = iter->second();
   gateway->hello();
}
```

Normal compilation and linking is fine (program output 0):

> g++ -std=c++17 -static-libstdc++ -c Main.cpp && g++ -std=c++17 -static-libstdc++ -c Impl.cpp

> g++ -std=c++17 -static-libstdc++ Impl.o Main.o && ./a

But if I put Impl.o into a static library, then it doesn't work:

> ar qc libtest.a Impl.o && g++ -std=c++17 -static-libstdc++ libtest.a Main.o && ./a

Apparently EntryInserter is compiled as weak symbol and is omitted during linking. What I don't understand is why the different behavior for linking an object vs linking an object from .a

I tested this on Linux (clang 10 and gcc 10) and Cygwin (gcc 9) and they seem to yield the same results

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with weak symbols.

> What I don't understand is why the different behavior for linking an object vs linking an object from .a

Because that's how linking works.

When you link directly to a `.o` file all its symbols are included in the link, whether they resolve undefined references or not.

But for a library, if there is no undefined reference to a symbol then the library doesn't get used.

Nothing in `Main.o` references anything defined in `Impl.o` so there are no undefined references. So when the symbols in `Impl.o` are defined in a static library, they aren't added to the executable.

Also, libraries need to be listed **after** the objects that use them, or the linker will ignore the library. See http://c-faq.com/lib/libsearch.html

To ensure the static library gets included in your link you can do:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -static-libstdc++ Main.o -Wl,--whole-archive libtest.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```